# Error processing variables with special characters in bash script

Tags: bash

I need help trying to find a solution to have a bash script be able to read file names with special characters. The user will start the script, but if the folder or the file has special characters, the script will fail or have an error. I have tried several options I found online, but I have not been able to make them work with the script.

The script is set up to take user input with the read command.

```sh
read -r -p "Enter directory name : " var1
```

If the user input is “accoutn&orders,” the script will fail due to the ‘&’ character as it won’t find the directory or file.

When the script looks for the file with specific extensions, the input folder name will be the path to copy the files to a different directory. The issue I am running into is that some of those files or directories have special characters, and the script cannot process the variables and cannot find the file when there are special characters.

The script uses a for loop to check every file in the directory, and if the file's name has a special character, it will fail the loop.

example file name:

```
file1@depot.rct
file2&logrecord.rct
```

```sh
cd $var1
```

```
ls: cannot access '/sharepool/comunityshare//'\''account.&.orders'\''': No such file or directory
line 141: cd: '/sharepool/comunityshare//'\''account.&.orders'\''': No such file or directory
```

I have tried using single quotes wrapping and bask slashes, but the variable is not readable.

Please note that I am not a coder or developer, I know some basic Linux commands, and I am trying to make this work while a better process is developed. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Show your code. `cd "$var1"` should work.  Single quotes will not.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To correctly highlight something as code, select it in the editor and press the `{}` button in the toolbar. This will make sure the code is presented the way you wanted it, including backslashes and such. Please also make sure to copy-paste everything exactly, since you currently have problems like slanted quotes and misspelled `accoutn` that maybe aren't in your code.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it identifies before asking questions here. (BTW, with respect to finding time to address the improvements suggested here: You can put your question on hold from being downvoted or close-voted by temporarily deleting it, editing it while it's deleted, and then undeleting it when you're done).

Comment: The code you posted is `read -r -p "Enter directory name : " var1` and `cd $var1`, and you say you enter `accoutn&orders` (misspelled, without dots). However, the error message mentions `/sharepool/comunityshare/` (misspelled, not in script or input) and `account.&.orders` (correct spelling with dots, but not mentioned in your list of example file names). Can you please clarify? I am guessing that you have a secret line `var1="/sharepool/comunityshare/"/$var1` in the script and actually enter `'account.&.orders'`, but it's hard to debug based on guesswork

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yes, that was a typo on my end, I should have copied and pasted the error and names.

Comment: if I used something like this to check for a special character in a string and add a backslash before the character; how can I have it check certain characters or exclude periods?

        if [ `expr "$filename" : ".*[!@#\$%^\&*()_+].*"` -gt 0 ];
        then 
            echo "This file name contain sspecial symbol"; 
            filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/\([^[:alnum:]]\)/\\\1/g')
        else
            echo "No special character found."
        fi

for example, if it contains any of the following ['!@#$%^&*()_+'] add a backslash before it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using this line.

```
filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/[&()@+*#!%^'\''^]/\\&/g')
```

That inserted a backslash if the variable had a special character.

account.&.orders to account.&.orders

Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: HI @emman5000 - to show your back-slash/quote you need to quote it with a back-slash - i.e. \\